# OpenMP with "collapse()" for nested for-loops performs worse when without

Tags: performance, openmp

This is my code:

```
double res1[NNN];  
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) schedule(dynamic) 
for (int i=0; i<NNN; i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<NNN;j++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<NNN;k++)
        {
            res1[i] = log(fabs(i*j*k));
        }
    }
}
std::cout<< res1[10] << std::endl;
```

When I use `collapse(3)` it takes ~50 sec; without `collapse(3)` only ~6-7 seconds. I am very puzzled by this behavior, since I would have expected a better performance with "collapse" than without.

Am I missing something?

---

I did some experiments and played with different configs:

(NNN = 2500 and 24 cores)

1. `schedule(STATIC)` && `collapse(3)` -> ~54 sec
2. `schedule(STATIC)` && `collapse(2)` ->  ~8 sec
3. `schedule(STATIC)` && `collapse(1)` ->  ~8 sec

I also tried with `DYNAMIC` schedule, but it takes enormous time (several minutes).

---

In my original problem, I have 4 DIM "for-loops" (4D array): 51x23x51x23.

What is the best way to use OpenMP/MPI to minimize running time? I have in total ~300 CPU cores. What is the best way to spread my array over these cores? The length of array is flexible (I can fit it to the number of CPUs in some way).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you got with `collapse(2)`? Also what happens when you change the `schedule` to `static`?

Comment: Could it be that the compiler optimizes away the loops? Technically, it only needs to keep the last value for res1[i], not all the intermediate values. Maybe it's missing that when collapse is in place.

Comment: Use MPI with one rank per node. Distribute the iteration over the outermost array index between the MPI ranks and then use OpenMP to distribute the inner iterations over the cores on each node. If nodes have more than one CPU socket with separate memory controller each, then run one MPI rank per CPU socket and set the number of OpenMP threads to be equal to the number of cores in a single socket.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing the concept of what is the impact of using dynamic scheduling on the OpenMP overhead.

Dynamic scheduling should be used to help us with load balance problems, where *each loop iteration can take a different amount of time*, and static iteration distribution would most likely create work imbalance between the different threads. Work imbalance leads to wasted CPU time as the threads that finish earlier simply wait for the other threads to finish. 
Dynamic scheduling overcomes that by distributing loop chunks on a first come, first served basis. But this adds overhead, since the OpenMP runtime system has to implement bookkeeping on which iteration was given out and which not and has to implement some type of synchronisation. Also, each thread must make at least one call to the OpenMP runtime every time it finishes its iteration block and goes looking for another one. With static scheduling all iteration blocks are precomputed initially and then each thread runs over its part without any interaction with the OpenMP runtime environment.

The most crucial difference between static and dynamic scheduling is the iteration chunk size (i.e. the number of consecutive loop iterations that each thread does before seeking to do work in another part of the iteration space). If omitted, the chunk size with static scheduling defaults to `#_of_iterations/#_of_threads` while the default chunk size for dynamic scheduling is `1`, i.e. each thread has to ask the OpenMP runtime for *each iteration* of the distributed loop.

What happens in your case is that without `collapse(3)` you have `NNN` iteration chunks of the outer loop and each thread runs `NNN*NNN` iterations (of the inner loops) before asking the OpenMP runtime for another iteration. When you collapse the loops, the number of iteration chunks grows to `NNN*NNN*NNN`, i.e. there are many more chunks and each thread is going to ask the OpenMP runtime for a chunk after each iteration.

This brings another problem when inner loops are collapsed with the outermost: it will happen that many threads would get iterations that have the same value of `i`, which would break the computation as the order of execution is not guaranteed and it might happen that the last thread that writes to `res1[i]` is not the one that executes the last iteration of both inner loops.